# C++ Returning a random value from a subset of a Vector

Tags: c++, vector, random, integer

Can someone help me figure out a way to return a value from a vector that has N values in sequential order. And the return value has to be in the upper half of the set.

For example,

If have a vector containing the following integers: 
{1, 2, 3. 4, 5, 6}

Return a random integer from {4,5,6}. I'm so stumped!

The end objective is to create a "weighted die" where the value of a roll returns a higher value. My solution is the aforementioned use of vectors.

```
void LoadedDie::loadedRoll(int numberOfSides)
{

    vector<int> diceSides(numberOfSides+1); 


    for (int index = 1; index < numberOfSides+1; index ++)

    {
        diceSides[index]=index; 
    }



    for (int index=1; index < numberOfSides+1; index ++)

    {
        cout << diceSides[index]; 
    }
}
```

So I have my dice created at this point, but can't figure out how to get a random value from the second half of the vector.

Comment: That is pretty specific. What have you tried/ thought of doing in the first place? show that you made an actual effort.

Comment: I have my vectors created but just need guidance on how to go about starting a search through my vector at a given index and then using the rand() to grab a value. I'm a beginner, and can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Show your code then, something is better than nothing... even though that posting the code kind of shows the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a random integer within a range, and use the subscript operator to access your vector.

```
int max = yourVector.size()-1; //-1 to stay in range
int min = max/2;
int randIndex = min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1));
yourVector[randIndex]; // this is a random int in your vector
```

This is slightly biased so you can use the following for an unbaised one:

```
#include <random>

int max = yourVector.size()-1; //-1 to stay in range
int min = max/2;
std::random_device seed;     // initialise a seed once
std::mt19937 numberGen(seed()); 
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> gen(min,max); 

int randIndex = gen(numberGen);
yourVector[randIndex]; // this is a random int in your vector
```

**EDIT**

As suggested you can use the .at() function in std::vector to be safe:

```
yourVector.at(randIndex);
```

Comment: But if the vector is changed, accessing it by index can be dangerous. Accessing it by using `at( )` is safer.

Comment: Ahh Ok that really helps.

Comment: @EvanCarslake: This code already uses the actual size of the vector, rather than hard-coding the length of 6.  The only way a "change" in the vector could cause issues is if it is resized, between calling `size()` and using the distribution, but there are no callbacks to user-provided code in between, so such a change could only happen on another thread.  And a race condition is undefined behavior no matter whether you use subscripting or `at()`.